# HTML | Table with columns that size to content AND columns that expand

Tags: html, css

In the following table, I want the first column and the last column (the ID and checkbox columns) to equal their content in size. Notice how both of those columns are wider than their content. I want them to size their content tightly.

I want the center columns (source and target) to expand to take up the remaining width of the table, but they should have the SAME width as each other. Source width should always equal target width.

I know that I could set the size of the first and last column to be fixed in px, but I want to avoid that if possible.

[image]

My code looks something like this (no styles):

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
      </th>
      <th>
        Source
      </th>
      <th>
        Target
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        hello
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set your table to 100% width, but define the columns that you want the width to remain only the size as its contents as being 1% width. This forces this column to take up at least 1%, but will expand to the size of the contents.

To ensure that the middle columns have an equal width, split the remaining 98% between the two. So set each one to 49%:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fit {
  width: 1%;
}

.even {
  width: 49%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fit">1</td>
    <td class="even">Content column 2</td>
    <td class="even">Content column 3</td>
    <td class="fit"><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fit">2</td>
    <td class="even">Content column 2</td>
    <td class="even">Extended content column 3</td>
    <td class="fit"><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="fit">3</td>
    <td class="even">Content column 2</td>
    <td class="even">Even more extended content column 3</td>
    <td class="fit"><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: If I expand the content of a row in the middle columns, it causes the balance of the middle two columns to no longer be even. Is there a way to ensure they are always the same size no matter their content? (For example, change "Content column 2" to "This is a test 123 321 asdf testing" and notice the change in size).

Comment: Yes, I think if you split the remaining 99% between the two columns, giving each 49%, this will make the two middle columns equal. I've updated the snippet to show this

Comment: Is there any way to do it with the ability to have multiple middle columns equal dynamically (ie not have to specify 49% because there could be 3,4,5 columns in the middle)?

Comment: Your solution plus JavaScript for making the 49% number dynamic worked for me! Thanks for the help